# How to use PrimeFaces getSelectedRowsCount?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:dataTable>` that has a checkbox column,

```
p:column selectionMode="multiple"
```

on submit, I'm trying to count the number of rows selected in JavaScript using,

```
tableID.getSelectedRowsCount()
```

and

```
$('tableID').getSelectedRowsCount()
```

but none of them is working. How can I make this work?

Comment: thanks, ill try this, im planning to use this to stop user from submitting the form if no rows were selected

Comment: i've already thought of that, im planning to use that as my last resort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found a way to make this work

first get your `p:datatable widgetvar` on a js var like this

```
var zzz = PrimeFaces.widgets['widgetVarName'];
```

and then you can now call `getSelectedRowsCount()` like this

```
zzz.getSelectedRowsCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

As carlo del rosario mentioned, you need to use the widgetVar set on the dataTable. Instead of using `PrimeFaces.widgets['wv']`, you can use the shortcut `PF('wv')` to access the widget and call the function directly without setting an intermediate var. So, the most concise way to get the number of rows selected would be:

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="wv">
...
</p:dataTable>
...

PF('wv').getSelectedRowsCount();
```

More dataTable client-side functions are documented in the user guide:
https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/

Comment: `PF('wv')`is a shortcut for `PrimeFaces.widgets['wv']` and in the other answer the var is not needed either, so effectively your answer is the same as the other

Comment: True, I was meaning to give the most concise answer. I'll note that in my answer.